# Convolution of shifted function with Delta Dirac Function

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta

We know that $f(t)*δ(t-a)=f(t-a)$. How about $f(t-a)*δ(t-a)$? (where * is convolution and $δ(t)$ is dirac delta function)

I think it's $f(t-a)*δ(t-a) = f(t-a)$ because convolution with delta function shifts the function to where the delta is. So if the function has already shifted to the same location as the delta - nothing happens and it stays the same shifted function. What do you think?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Let $g(t)=f(t-a)$ and apply your first result to $g(t)\ast \delta(t-a)$

Comment: Your notation doesn't make sense to me; the convolution product acts on functions, whose arguments cannot be different; indeed, $(f \ast g)(t) = \int f(x)g(t-x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int f(t-x)g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @Abezhiko - in your notation, let $g(t) = \delta(t-a)$. Then the first statement claims that $(f * g)(t) = f(t-a)$ for all $t$. And the question is, when $F(t) = f(t-a)$, what is $(F*g)(t)$?